# C# Multi-Server Sockets application

Tags: c#-3.0

I am not exactly sure how to proceed with multiple server communicating with each other, by that i mean, example: User A on Server 1 want to send a private message to User B on Server 2, the User A send the message to his respective server(Server 1) and from this point how Server 1 is supposed to transmit the message to User B?

Comment: What mechanism are the servers using to communicate with each other?  Is there any way the servers know where (on which server) each user is located?

Comment: do Server1 and Server2 have public ip? can you store messages in the external storage and requery periodicaly from another server to see if any message exists?

Comment: @fvu Actually i am not sure how to communicate between two server. Thats why i am asking?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt Server1 and Server 2 has the same ip but different port. I can create the asynchronous server and the clients, but all on one server.

Comment: you can use WCF Duplex with pipe binding, I am not sure if this helps because the question is really unclear for me

Answer (score 0):

With the minimal information in the question it's very hard to point you in the right direction, here are some pointers to possible solutions for the problem of sending messages to destinations you cannot readily locate at the time of sending the message:

1. [Microsoft MQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), maybe not the freshest product in the message broker arena, but as far as I know its a nice product.
2. You could use a [XMPP (Jabber) server](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/), that's the same technology Google Talk is using.  Lots of [libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) are available to integrate that protocol with most common languages.
3. Any of the existing open source messaging softwares with connectors for .net languages like [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)

An article that could also help you to see clearer in your requirements is [this comparison between message systems based on a broker and those that don't use a broker](http://www.zeromq.org/whitepapers%3abrokerless). Both solutions I suggest above use brokers by the way.